# How can I draw Lines from Fractal Points, that would extend to the point where price crosses through it

Tags: pine-script

I have been trying to draw lines from certain fractal points, and extend it until price closes above or below these prices. I don't seem to get the right algorithm/code for it.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the y intercept with some simple algebra. This is a simple example using the last two daily open prices. You should be able to substitute (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) with your pivot coordinates to determine the current `y` value given `x` (current `bar_index`).

```
new_day = change(time("D")) != 0

var int x1 = na
var float y1 = na

var int x2 = na
var float y2 = na

if new_day
    x1 := x2
    y1 := y2
    x2 := bar_index
    y2 := open

int x = bar_index

y = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x - x1) + y1

l = line.new(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2, extend = extend.none)
line.delete(l[1])

l2 = line.new(x1 = x2, y1 = y2, x2 = x, y2 = y, extend = extend.none, style = line.style_dashed)
line.delete(l2[1])

la = label.new(x = x, y = y, style = label.style_label_up, text = "Calculated point\ny(price) given x (current bar_index)")
label.delete(la[1])

la_1 = label.new(x = x1, y = y1, style = label.style_label_up, text = "Point 1 (x1, y1)")
label.delete(la_1[1])

la_2 = label.new(x = x2, y = y2, style = label.style_label_up, text = "Point 2 (x2, y2)")
label.delete(la_2[1])

crossover_condition = open < y and close > y
plotshape(crossover_condition, location = location.belowbar, style = shape.triangleup, color = color.lime, size = size.small)
```